# Counting number sub-space countain a particular member

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Assume  $\mathbb V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb {Z_2}\ $ that  $ \dim (\mathbb V)= n \ $ and $S \prec \mathbb V ,\dim(S)=k$  and let   $ \ a=\underbrace{(1, 0,\cdots ,0)}_{n\text{ times}} $ we know that $ \ W_H(a)=1 \ $ (Hamming weight) I want to calculate $$P(a \in S )=\text{?} $$ & $$ P(\text{$S$ contain a vector of Hamming weight $1$})= \text {?} $$

Does anyone have an idea to solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The $k$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional space that contain a specific non-zero vector $a$, are in one-to-one correspondece with the $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace of the $(n-1)$-dimensional space $\Bbb V/\langle a\rangle$.
Note that this does not depend on the Hamming weight.

Comment: Your answer is right but how can i calculate the second probability equation?thx about your hint

Comment: I got it tanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I use Hagen's hint  to calculate $P(a\in S)$ and $ P(\text{ $S$ contain a vector of Hamming weight $1$  })$

$P(a\in S)= \frac{\binom {n-1} {k-1}_2}{\binom n k_2}=\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{n}-1}$.

With Inclusion-exclusion principle & that every vectors that $w_H(b)=1$ are independent I calculate  $ P(\text{ $S$ contain a vector of Hamming weight $1$   } )=\sum_{i=1}^k  = (-1)^{i+1}\binom{\binom{n}{1}}{i}\frac{(2^{k}-1)(2^{k}-2)\cdots (2^{k}-2^{(i-1)})}{(2^{n}-1)(2^{n}-2)\cdots (2^{n}-2^{(i-1)})}$.

Define the Gaussian binomial coefficient, $\binom n k_q=\dfrac{(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots(q^n-q^{k-1})}{(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots(q^k-q^{k-1})}$ by the number of $k$ dimensional subspaces of a $n$ dimensional subspace.